# Base SAS: Restructuring a Data Set for Cross Tabulation

Tags: sas, crosstab, transpose

I need to restructure a data set in order to produce a cross tab output/data set. . The question I'm trying to answer is  what additional products were purchased after initial sign up purchases and what are the product combinations -  So, if  a customer bought prod3 at signup they also eventually bought prod2 and prod4 .

The data set I start with looks like this. Notice some of the product purchases dates are the same as the startup date

```
ID  Signup_dt   Prod_type   Purchase_Date
2232    4-Jun-14    prod1   4-Jun-14
2232    4-Jun-14    prod2   4-Jun-14
2232    4-Jun-14    prod3   4-Jun-14
2232    4-Jun-14    prod4
2232    4-Jun-14    prod5   4-Aug-14
4545    12-Jun-14   prod1
4545    12-Jun-14   prod2   13-Sep-14
4545    12-Jun-14   prod3   12-Jun-14
4545    12-Jun-14   prod4   12-Nov-14
4545    12-Jun-14   prod5   12-Jun-14
```

I need to restructure the data set so it looks like this:

```
ID  startup_month   Poducts Purchase_at_Start_Up    prod1   prod2   prod3   prod4   prod5
2232    June         prod1            1                                               1
2232    June         prod2            1                                               1
2232    June         prod3            1                                               1
2232    June         prod4                      
2232    June         prod5                      
4545    June         prod1                      
4545    June         prod2                      
4545    June         prod3            1                      1                        1
4545    June         prod4                      
4545    June         prod5            1                      1                        1
```

And then a summary data set which gives the totals/counts  of the product combinations

```
Startup_month   Poducts Purchase_Start_up_count prod1_dt    prod2_dt    prod3_dt    prod4_dt prod5_dt
June              prod1           1                                                             1
June              prod2           1                                                             1
June              prod3           2                1                                            2
June              prod4                     
June              prod5           1                1                                            1
```

I'm having trouble visualizing how to program for this. I'm been using different combinations of proc transpose and proc freq but  I can't come close to the desired output.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you are hoping to gain from the first summary table (e.g. why is prod5 only one for the first 3 rows rather than the first 5). That said you can build a similar summary using a combination of proc transpose and data steps:

```
data have;
    infile datalines dlm = ",";
    input 
        ID
        Signup_dt date9.
        Prod_type $
        Purchase_Date date9.;
    format Signup_dt Purchase_Date yymmdd10.;
datalines;
2232,4-Jun-14,prod1,4-Jun-14
2232,4-Jun-14,prod2,4-Jun-14
2232,4-Jun-14,prod3,4-Jun-14
2232,4-Jun-14,prod4,
2232,4-Jun-14,prod5,4-Aug-14
4545,12-Jun-14,prod1,
4545,12-Jun-14,prod2,13-Sep-14
4545,12-Jun-14,prod3,12-Jun-14
4545,12-Jun-14,prod4,12-Nov-14
4545,12-Jun-14,prod5,12-Jun-14
;
run;
/* Create month variable and check if purchased at signup */
data want1;
    set have;
    startup_month = strip(put(Signup_dt, monname9.));
    if Signup_dt = Purchase_Date then Purchase_at_Start_Up = 1;
    drop Purchase_Date Signup_dt;
run;
/* Create dummy flag for transpose*/ 
data have1;
    set have;
    if Purchase_Date then flag = 1;
run;
/* Transpose to get product variables by ID */
proc transpose data = have1 out = want2 (drop =  _NAME_);  
    by ID;
    id Prod_type;
    var flag;
run;
/* Combine the two */
data want;
    merge want1 want2;
    by ID;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Your summary tables are incorrect.  id 4545 has sign-up purchases for prod5 but no additional purchases for that product.   It is reasonably clear what you are trying to achieve.  The solution above is also incorrect.  It joins additional sales to products that did not have any sign-up purchases.

Your first table summary table by id, startup_month and product;

```
proc sql;
    create table want_sql1                      as  

    select  sign_up_purchases.id
        ,strip(put(sign_up_purchases.Signup_dt, monname9.)) as startup_month
        ,sign_up_purchases.prod_type                as Products

        ,sum (case when sign_up_purchases.Signup_dt eq sign_up_purchases.Purchase_Date then 1 end) 
                                        as Purchase_at_Start_Up

        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod1)               as prod1    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod2)               as prod2    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod3)               as prod3    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod4)               as prod4    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod5)               as prod5    

    from    have    as  sign_up_purchases

/*      get a summary of additional purchases. */
    left    join
        (   select  id
                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod1' then 1 end)
                                        as prod1    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod2' then 1 end)
                                        as prod2    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod3' then 1 end)
                                        as prod3    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod4' then 1 end)
                                        as prod4    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod5' then 1 end)
                                        as prod5    

            from    have    

            where   Signup_dt   ne  Purchase_Date 
            and Purchase_Date is    not null

            group   by  id
        )                   as  additional_purchases
/*      Join by id and products with sign_up purchases. */
    on  sign_up_purchases.id        eq  additional_purchases.id
    and sign_up_purchases.Signup_dt eq  sign_up_purchases.Purchase_Date         

    group   by  1,2,3
    ;
quit;   


proc compare 
    base=want_sql1
    compare=want
    ;
run;
```

Your second summary by startup_month and product;
    proc sql;
        create table want_sql2                      as

```
    select strip(put(sign_up_purchases.Signup_dt, monname9.))   as startup_month

        ,sign_up_purchases.prod_type                as Products

        ,sum (case when sign_up_purchases.Signup_dt eq sign_up_purchases.Purchase_Date then 1 end) 
                                        as Purchase_at_Start_Up

        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod1_dt)            as prod1_dt    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod2_dt)            as prod2_dt    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod3_dt)            as prod3_dt    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod4_dt)            as prod4_dt    
        ,sum (additional_purchases.prod5_dt)            as prod5_dt    

    from    have    as  sign_up_purchases

/*      get a summary of additional purchases. */
    left    join
        (   select  id
                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod1' then 1 end)
                                        as prod1_dt    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod2' then 1 end)
                                        as prod2_dt    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod3' then 1 end)
                                        as prod3_dt    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod4' then 1 end)
                                        as prod4_dt    

                ,sum (case when prod_type eq 'prod5' then 1 end)
                                        as prod5_dt    

            from    have    

            where   Signup_dt   ne  Purchase_Date 
            and Purchase_Date is    not null

            group   by  id
        )                   as  additional_purchases
/*      Join by id and products with sign_up purchases. */
    on  sign_up_purchases.id        eq  additional_purchases.id
    and sign_up_purchases.Signup_dt eq  sign_up_purchases.Purchase_Date         

    group   by  1,2
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version involving Data Steps, Proc Transpose and Proc Summary producing your 2 outputs (see want1 and want2).

Much more work in this than the SQL version as is the case for most applications.  SQL is more intuitive, powerful and flexible.

```
/*  identify additional Purchases. */
data additional_Purchases1;
    set have;

/*  We need records for all products regardless if there is an   */
/*  additional Purchase as we want proc transpose to create columns  */
/*  for all products (prod1-prod5).  Not just those that had     */
/*  additional Purchases.                                            */
    if      Signup_dt   ne  Purchase_Date 
        and Purchase_Date ne    .
        then    additional_Purchases = 1;
run;



/*  summarise additional Purchases. */
proc summary nway 
    data = additional_Purchases1    ;
    class id Prod_type;
    var additional_Purchases;
    output out=additional_Purchases2
        sum=additional_Purchases
        ;
run;



/* Transpose additional Purchases by ID and product*/
proc transpose 
    data = additional_Purchases2 
    out = additional_Purchases (drop =  _NAME_ )
    ;  
    by ID;
    id Prod_type;
    var additional_Purchases;
run;



/*  Join Sign-up purchases to additional purchases for each Id and Product. */
data want1 
    (keep = id startup_month Products Purchase_at_Start_Up prod1-prod5) 
    ;

    format id           10.
        startup_month
        Products        $10.
        Purchase_at_Start_Up 10.
        ;

    merge   have    (   in=sign_up_purchases 
                rename = (prod_type=Products)
            )
        additional_Purchases    
            (   in=additional_purchases 
                rename =(prod1-prod5 = oprod1-oprod5)
            )
        ;
    by id;

    if  sign_up_purchases;

    startup_month = strip (put(Signup_dt, monname9.));


/*  Tried updating Prod1 - Prod5 (set to missing when no signup purchase)  */
/*  but re-assignment was retained on next matching observation regardless */
/*  of values of prod1-prod5 on input table. */

    ARRAY oPROD oprod1-oprod5;
    ARRAY PROD prod1-prod5;

/*  Get additional Purchases for products with purchased at signup.      */
    if  Signup_dt = Purchase_Date 
        then    do;
                Purchase_at_Start_Up = 1;
                do over prod;
                    prod = oprod;
                end;
            end;        
run;


/*  Summarise Sign-up and additional Purchases by startup month and product.     */
proc summary 
    nway
    data=want1
    ;
    class startup_month products;
    var Purchase_at_Start_Up prod1-prod5;
    output  out = want2 (drop=_type_ _freq_)
        sum = Purchase_at_Start_up_count prod1_dt prod2_dt prod3_dt prod4_dt prod5_dt
        ;
quit;
```